# Fill width of div with HTML5 number field

Tags: css, html

I have a form with an HTML5 number field and a submit button. I want the submit button to be its natural width and my number field to fill the rest of the form's container. My code looks like this.

```
<div class="form">
  <div class="input">
    <input type="number" name="test">
  </div>
  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.form {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
}

input {
  padding: 14px;
}

input[type="number"] {
  width: 100%;
}

.input {
  float: left;
  padding: 14px;
}

.submit {
  float: left;
  padding: 11px 0;
}
```

My problem seems to be setting a fluid width on the `input[type="number"]`.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ca4pkjxm/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#phone-280 {
  width: 280px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#phone-400 {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
input {
  padding: 14px;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type="number"] {
  width: 100%;
}
.input {
  padding: 14px;
  flex: 1;
}
.submit {
  padding: 11px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="phone-280">
  <div class="form">
    <div class="input">
      <input type="number" name="test">
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="phone-400">
  <div class="form">
    <div class="input">
      <input type="number" name="test">
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the floats and set both the input and the submit button to have `display:inline-block`. Then align them and set a width of the `input` block to your liking.

In the following fiddle, I only fixed the bottom input element with this method.

https://jsfiddle.net/ca4pkjxm/3/

```
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#phone-280 {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#phone-600 {
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.form {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
}

input {
  padding: 14px;
}

input[type="number"] {
  width: 420px;
}

.input {
  padding: 14px;
}

.submit {
  padding: 11px 0;
}

.input,.submit{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: The two `phone` divs were just example widths. I am trying to avoid setting a px width on `input[type="number"]` because I am not sure what the width will be.

Comment: Why are you setting a px width for the container then?

Comment: I am not in my actual usage. I just did it on the jsfiddle to show examples of responsive widths and how the submit button wrapped below the number field.

Comment: You can use percentages instead. Play around with the following fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ca4pkjxm/4/